# Angular2 ngrx/store with multiple login attempts

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

In looking through a couple of ngrx examples (https://github.com/SekibOmazic/ngrx-auth-example) and (https://github.com/ngrx/angular2-store-example) they both create a subscription to the store, and then make REST API calls.

I've modified both of their code to return errors and yet the subscriptions remain in tact (e.g. returning a 404 when trying to login). I can see the error in the console yet I can login again.

In my code, I have a nearly identical setup, yet a failed login response kills my subscription (as near as I can tell).

What magic do I need in order for a 4XX error response codes to not kill my subscription?

```js
private actions$ = new BehaviorSubject<Action>({ type: actions.INIT, payload: null })

constructor(
  public http: Http,
  private store: Store<AppStore>
) {
  let logins = this.actions$
    .filter(action => { debug('ACTION', action); return action.type === actions.LOGIN_USER })
    .do(() => { debug('DISPATCH'); this.store.dispatch({ type: actions.LOGIN_REQUEST }) })
    .mergeMap(action => this.http.post('/auth/login', JSON.stringify(action.payload)))
    .share();

  let loginSuccess$ = logins
    .filter((payload: IResponse) => payload.data.token !== null)
    .map((payload: IResponse) => ({ type: actions.USER_AUTHENTICATED, payload: payload.data }));

  let loginFailure$ = logins
    .filter((payload: IResponse) => payload.data.token === null)
    .map((payload: IResponse) => ({ type: actions.LOGIN_FAILURE, payload: payload.data }));

  Observable
    .merge(loginSuccess$, loginFailure$)
    .subscribe((action: Action) => this.store.dispatch(action))
}

login(payload: ILogin) {
  this.actions$.next({ type: actions.LOGIN_USER, payload });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is more to do with RxJS itself as opposed to anything with ngrx. An error will end a stream, unless you a) handle it in the .subscribe(next, err) handler, or use the .catch() operator or similar.

For example

```
let loginFailures$ = http.get('failurl')
  .map(res => res.json())
  //handle error with catch
  .catch(err => {
    //return a 'fixed' observable
    return Observable.of({ type: actions.LOGIN_FAILURE, payload: err })
  })
  .subscribe(action => store.dispatch(action));
```

Comment: There are too much downsides to this approach. Please look into this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141969/designing-redux-state-tree/142382#142382

Comment: @StavAlfi - this link is not up to date anymore. Can you update?

Comment: At the time , I asked the same question in github. https://github.com/ngrx/effects/issues/52